# How to set up Django models with two types of users with very different attributes

Tags: python, database-design, heroku, django-models, django-1.4

*Note: I've since [asked this question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779068/setting-up-two-different-types-of-users-in-django-1-5-1-6) given the updates to Django's user model since version 1.5.*

I'm rebuilding and making improvements to an already existing Django site and moving it over from Webfaction to Heroku, and from Amazon's SimpleDB to Heroku Postgres (though testing locally on Sqllite3 when developing).  A lot of what I'm doing is moving over to use built-in Django functionality, like the Django admin, user authentication, etc.

Conceptually, the site has two kinds of users: Students and Businesses.  The two types of users have completely different permissions and information stored about them.  This is so much the case that in the original structure of the site, we set up the data model as follows:

```
Users
    ID (primary_key)
    Business_or_Student ('B' if business, 'S' if student)
    email (unique)
    password (hashed, obviously)
    ...

Students
    ID (Foreignkey on Users)
    <more information>
    ...

Businesses
    ID (Foreignkey on Users)
    <more information>
    ...
```

This worked pretty well for us, and we had the bare-bones user information in the Users table, and then any more detailed information in the Students and Businesses tables.  Getting a user's full profile required something along this pseudocode:

```
def get_user_profile(id):
    if Users(id=id).Business_or_Student = 'B':
        return Businesses(id=id)
    else:
        return Students(id=id)
```

In moving over, I've found that Django's built-in `User` object has pretty limited functionality, and I've had to extend it with a `UserProfile` class I've created, and then had additional `Student` and `Business` tables.  Given all of the patching I'm doing with this in the Django admin, and being relatively unfamiliar with Django models since I always did it differently, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, or if I should just stick *all* of the information for businesses and students in the `UserProfile` table and just differentiate the two with different groups, or if there's even some way to do this all in the built-in `User` object.

Since businesses and students also have different interfaces, I'm seriously considering setting up the two as different apps within my Django project, and so separating their views, models, etc. entirely.  That would look something like:

```
MyProject/
    MyProject/ (project folder, Django 1.4)
    mainsite/
    students/
    businesses/
```

One of my biggest concerns is with the Django Admin.  In extending `User`, I already had to add the following code:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )
```

However, I would like the information for the Business or Student aspects of the user to show up in the Django admin when that `User` is pulled up, but the `ForeignKey` part of the model is in the `Student` and `Business` model since every `Student`/`Business` has a `User` but every `User` has only one `Student` **or** one `Business` object connected with it.  I'm not sure how to add a conditional Inline for the Admin.

**Question: Given this structure and these concerns, what is the best way to set up this site, particularly the data model?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but it will give you an idea of where to start.

- Create a `UserProfile` model in `mainsite`. This will hold any common attributes for both types of users. Relate it to the `User` model with a `OneToOne(...)` field.
- Create two more models in each app, (student/business), `Business` and `Student`, which have `OneToOne` relationships each with `UserProfile` (or inherit from `UserProfile`). This will hold attributes specific to that type of users. Docs: [Multitable inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) / [OneToOne Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)
- You *may* add a field in `UserProfile` to distinguish whether it is a business or student's profile.

Then, for content management:

- Define the `save()` functions to automatically check for conflicts (e.g. There is an entry for both `Business` and `Student` associated with a `UserProfile`, or no entries).
- Define the `__unicode__()` representations where necessary.

Comment: I started out with doing this, but then I switched the `OneToOne` relationship between `Student` and `UserProfile` to `Student` and `User` because the Django admin wouldn't recognize the username/email of the `UserProfile` objects, since those were stored in `User` rather than `UserProfile`.  When adding a new Businesses, the `OneToOne` relationship dropdown would simply list `UserProfile Object` over and over again until I changed it to `User`, when it started listing usernames.  I'm worried about stuff like that happening in other areas.  Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Yes, `UserProfile` links to `User`, which django uses to represent an user. To mask your dropdown problem, add `__unicode__()` method in `UserProfile` to return `self.user.username`. This is show username in dropdown, however will still link to `UserProfile`.

Comment: Thank you, that last bit was genius.  I'm going to leave the question open for a few days to see what other responses I get, but you've been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understood your problem... maybe this can work? You create a abstract CommonInfo class that is inherited in into the different Sub-classes (student and businesses)

```
class CommonUser(models.Model):      
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    <any other common fields>

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Student(CommonUser):
    <whatever>

class Business(CommonUser):
    <whatever>
```

In this case the models will be created in the DB with the base class fields in each table. Thus when you are working with Students you run a

```
students = Students.objects.get.all()
```

to get all your students including the common information.

Then for each student you do:

```
for student in students:
    print student.user.username
```

The same goes for Business objects.

To get the student using a user:

```
student = Student.objects.get(user=id)
```

The username will be unique thus when creating a new Student or Business it will raise an exception if an existing username is being saved.

Forgot to add the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)